# Export audio track from AVI with two channels with VLC

Tags: linux, audio, vlc-media-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Audio stream from XVID files](https://superuser.com/questions/56093/remove-audio-stream-from-xvid-files)

I have an AVI file with two different audio tracks (English and Hungarian). I want convert this AVI file to another which has only the Hungarian audio track (I don't care about the English track). How can I do this with VLC?

Comment: What about using VirtualDub?

Comment: @Darius do you think with VD can I solve this problem easy? If it counts I'm using linux.

Comment: If you head [here](http://www.techkings.org/dvd-cd-guides-tutorials/14383-how-remove-audio-stream-avi-file.html) and start reading from the Download section you should be able to do it.